# What are the odds of a pitcher hitting a bird?

Tags: probability

On March 24th 2001, [Randy Johnson Hit a Bird With His Fastball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sIiajEEETw)  .

What are the chances on any given pitch of hitting a bird?

I searched online and I mostly found 2 types of answers.

[Some people](https://np.reddit.com/r/nevertellmetheodds/comments/61fgln/on_this_day_16_years_ago_randy_johnson_exploded_a/dfe8g36/) makes "guesses" using estimates. We know how many doves there are in the US, how much space they take up and how much space a ball takes up and crunching all the numbers they get an answer.

[Some others](https://www.quora.com/What-were-the-odds-of-Randy-Johnson-killing-that-bird-with-his-pitch) take a different approach: they take for granted that this event has happend only once in the MLB and try to calculate all the pitches that have been thrown. The answer then is just 1 over all the pitches thrown.

Are there any other ways to calculate this probability? Is one method better, or more correct than the other?

Comment: Are you asking about birds? Or doves?

Comment: Not necessarily a dove, could be any bird, but we can assume a dove so that we know the size of the bird.

Comment: MLB = ? ....... for illiterate people like me ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: major-league baseball

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. I am going to go to bed light-hearted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not 1 over all the pitches thrown. You are conditioning on an event which has already happened, which is very bad.

To see why this reasoning is erroneous, let's suppose that you are right, and that it was a dove. Then by your logic, the probability of hitting a dove is exactly the same as the probability of hitting a bird -- they have both happened once in MLB history. But [that's absoid](https://www.mamalisa.com/blog/spring-has-sprung-the-grass-is-riz/).

Comment: So the correct answer is the first one?